# sending data through JSON(AJAX function) but not able to access the controller of respective page

Tags: php, ajax, json

This is my JavaScript function which I have included in HEAD tag:

```
function test()
{

//enter code here
$.ajax({
      url: 'test?msgto='+document.getElementById('Select1').value,
      dataType: 'json',
      type : 'GET',
      success: function(result)
      {
        //  console.log(result);
          alert('test1');
        //  alert(string(result[0]['Select1']) );

        //  alert(result[0]['TextArea1']);
           //document.getElementById('Text1').Value = ;// string(result[0]['location']);

      }


    });

 }
```

and I want to send data to my PHP controller using this function on Cilck event of a button. I have written the following code for GETACTION()

```
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    //echo('Get');
    $msgfrom = 1;                    //$this->_getparam('usrid');
    $msgto = $this->_getparam('msgto');

    $sql =  "call select_messages(".$msgfrom.",".$msgto.");";
    $data = Zend_Db_Table::getDefaultAdapter()->query($sql)->fetchAll();
    $this->_helper->json($data);
```

But while on clicking I am not getting any output or result....
Kindly Guide me as soon as possible..... :)

Comment: whats HTML looks like. Can you post part of it which states Select1. also the path to action should be relative like /test/? can that be a problem

Answer (score 1):

Several misuses there.

Firstly, are you sure GETACTION() retrieves the /test path?

Secondly, in your JS code, I'm not sure you are calling the right path.

You'd better use this :

```
$.ajax({
  type: 'GET',
  url: '/test', // Notice the '/' at the beginning
  data: {
    msgto: $('#Select1').val(), // Since you're using jQuery, do it all the way :)
  }
  success: function(result) {
    alert(result);
  }
});
```

Notice the slash at the beginning of the `url` parameter. It means: "starting after the domain name". Also, you don't need the use the verbose `document.getElementById()` when you're using jQuery :).

Lastly, see the `data` parameter. jQuery will automatically build the correct URL before sending the AJAX request. I think it keeps your code cleaner.

Comment: Hi Davies, really thanx for your concern.... I have used the above code provide by u....!! Bu now its showing(In Console of chrome) that "TEST IS NOT DEFINED".... and kindly guide me also in a way, that how to check the output for it.....!!

Comment: Hi, I'm not Davies :) It looks like you forgot the quotes around '/test'. Check your code.